# Stack Exchange Sites Tag Does Not Show All "Your Communities"

Tags: discussion, community, stackexchange

The very last tag on the top right hand side on StackExchange is for showing all Stack Exchange sites and communities. However, when clicking on it for the drop down view, it doesn't show all my communities but only 9 of them, you can't scroll down to view any more of "Your Communities" neither.

Is that the limit of showing "Your Communities" (maximum 9 communities)? Is there a way to scroll down to view all my communities on this tag, not just the first 9 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 11 listed on my list - added one using “edit” just last night, and it scrolls through them all fine.

So, I did notice I had to repeat the “add” routine twice before it saved it as it should - or I was being stupid and not actually hitting save ... :)

Comment: Dohhhh...! I made the fatal error by not scrolling down after "Add", hence didn't even spot the save button! I am a numpty.